# Task :react-native-screens:javaPreCompileDebug error in React Navigation 5.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I've created a React-Native project with the following command :

```
react-native init samplerouting
```

Then I enabled navigation with the following steps([based on its documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)):

1-

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

2-

```
npm install 
react-native-reanimated 
react-native-gesture-handler 
react-native-screens 
react-native-safe-area-context 
@react-native-community/masked-view
```

3-Add the following two lines to `dependencies` section in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

4-I Modified the `MainActivity.java` as below

```
package com.samplerouting;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "samplerouting";
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
        return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }

}
```

5-Then add the following at the top of my entry file (index.js)

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Finish, I want to run my project only on android device, That's why I reject the following steps:

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```

Now, When I run my project

```
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

I get the following error

> > Task :react-native-screens:javaPreCompileDebug FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings.

**NOTE:I tried the following command but it does not work**

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "samplerouting",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: @AbolfaziR still you facing issue? Because I followed same steps and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Sahil Kothari - It's your right, my problem was related to SDK, I update my SDK, It worked, Thanks a lot

Comment: @AblfaziR Great. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to `Gradle`.

That's why I updated my `SDK`, so It worked perfectly.

Needless to say :

In `Environment-variable` We have to add  the following 3 variables  :

**1-** ANDROID_HOME :(Your SDK path) J:\ReactNative\AndroidSDK\Android\Sdk

**2-** JAVA_HOME :(Your JDK path) C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231

**3-** platform-tools :(Your PLATFORM-TOOLS path) J:\ReactNative\AndroidSDK\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

**NOTE:** *The path above is on my computer, provide your own path*